# Apache Flink - Case class to Json for Kafka producer

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I, go to case class in Apache Flink with Scala. I want to turn it into Json to send it on a Kafka topic.
it's comes from a DataStream that went for a RichMapFunction

What would be the best strategy?

Example:

```
case class MySchema(
  someObj1: Some[String],
  someObj2: Some[String],
  someObj3: Some[String],
  obj1: String,
  obj2: String,
  obj3: String,
  intObj1: Int,
  intObj2: Int
)
```

Comment: Look into [circe](https://circe.github.io/circe/)

Comment: It's perfect for me, thanks.  myDataStream.map(_.asJson.noSpaces)